# What is the relationship between specific gravity and boiling point?

Tags: specific-gravity, boil-kettle

I know that adding sugar increases the boiling point of water, but by how much? Searched the web and can't find an answer.

Reason for asking is that a food grade Nylon 66 component I'm considering using in a BK is rated up to 110°C. Initially I thought that would give an adequate safety margin, but now wondering how hot sweet wort might get. I tend not to go bigger than SG 1.100.

If it helps, assume the BK is at sea level and the wort gravity is due to the addition of maltose alone (or, if it makes any difference, I guess sucrose would be fine for an approximation).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be fine with your nylon

According to [this boiling point explanation](https://socratic.org/questions/what-is-the-boiling-point-of-sugar-solution-at-atmospheric-pressure-how-do-we-ca) where the boiling point is raised by 2.8 C, you'd need a SG of over 1.350 (round number, but I think the point is clear) to even raise the boiling point by 3 degree C!

I personally think the physics in the linked example is hard to understand, but suffice to say that if you keep your SG at around 1.100 then your boiling point will be less than 102 C

Comment: Great, I'm reassured, thanks!